# Animations lag on Gnome because of my GTX 1050ti on 4k monitor?

Tags: gnome

Animations on my 4k monitor are sometimes laggy. For instance, 1 in 10 times I open the overview (this is the most noticeable one). On Ubuntu and Arch, and even ElementaryOS happens the same. But on my 1080p one doesn't seem to happen.
I suspect its because of the graphics card, so I was thinking to buy a Rx 550 since I read AMD Graphic Cards are better supported on Linux.

Comment: What is the refresh rate?  Is it a *monitor* or a *TV*?

Comment: 60 Hz. Is a monitor: DELL P2415Q

Comment: "laggy" is not well defined. Can you be more descriptive in your question by giving specific examples?  All we know from your question is that one in ten times it "happens the same".  What exactly happens?  A 1050Ti is not going to have any touble running your desktop, so I'm not even sure you have come to the correct conclusions.

Comment: With "laggy" I mean that the animation goes less than 60 fps, idk how much less, probably 20 fps or something like that.
Now I've noticed that it happens more frecuently on Ubuntu than in Arch. In Arch it was like 1 in 10 times I use the Activities Overview. With Ubuntu probably every 5 instances or something like that.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?